# Chromatic number of a particular graph

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, graph-colouring

Assume I have a parametrized graph. The parameters are two integers $x$ and $y<x$.
Let $S(x)=\{1, \ldots, x\}$.
The vertices of the graph are all the subsets of $S(x)$ of size $y$. Two vertices share an edge if their intersection is empty.
I need to find the **chromatic number** of this graph.
Is this problem NP-hard ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph

Comment: @AndreasBjörklund actualy I don't think you needed to shift this to a comment: your answer is exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: @SureshVenkat The OP asked for the chromatic index, not the chromatic number as I first thought. I don't see anything about the chromatic index in the wikipage, but at any rate it is good to know the name of this graph family.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake, it is the chromatic number I am looking for. Thank you Andreas.

Comment: Andreas pointed out the wikipedia page, and it says the chromatic number is x-2y+2.

Comment: @AndreasBjörklund maybe you should undelete the answer now :)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question, I should ask you before editing... Despite this, I am still curious about the chromatic index of Kneser graphs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph